# ErrorListener missing when using maven-jaxb-plugin with eclipse and m2e

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, jaxb

I have setup a project just for the plugin "`org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin"`. It works but I don't like the error message displayed within the Eclipse editor for the "pom.xml". The message states:

```
Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate: com/sun/xml/bind/api/ErrorListener
```

The pom and by this the whole project ist marked to be in error.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.gombers.lernen.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>PlayWithJAXB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <show>private</show>
                    <nohelp>true</nohelp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <useDependenciesAsEpisodes>true</useDependenciesAsEpisodes>
                    <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/jaxb</outputDirectory>
                    <packageName>de.gombers.lernen.jaxb.generated</packageName>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaFiles>Employee.xsd</schemaFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>


    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JAXB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb22-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-settings</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-container-default</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-9-stable-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-jxc</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- HELPERS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.gombers</groupId>
            <artifactId>BasicTools</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LOGGING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUNIT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON converter -->
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My "`mvn validate`" command does not state any error, and the claimed ErrorListener is provided with the artifact "`com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core`". And as already said, when running the project to generate sources it works  fine. Has anybody running this plugin and can share his pom.xml?

Comment: I'm totally lost now. I tried with this pom.xml:

Comment: I'm totally lost now. I tried with this pom.xml:
1. import to a new Eclipse(Mars) Workspace
2. build from scratch within a new Eclipse(Mars) workspace
3. Build from scratch within a new Eclipse(Kepler) Workspace with a new initial local repository
for all three of the samples I failed with "generate-sources" out of Eclipse UI, but line command "mvn generate-sources" works fine.

Comment: Provided in `org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core`.

Comment: Thank you, But using this doesn't change anything in Eclipse behaviour. It seems to be an Eclipse problem; but if so; it probably would have been known to the community already. The error says that the exception is thrown "at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:168)"

Comment: Used now the very same pom on a different computer with it's own local repository. But within Eclipse the pom is still marked being in error because class ErrorListener is missing. I'm now pretty surem there is really a problem with Eclipse and/or the m2e-plugin.
Have replaced the whole bunch of <!-- JAXB --> dependencies by 
 <!-- JAXB -->
   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.11</version>
  </dependency>
now; with the same result. Can anybody confirm my problem by using my pom.xml for a new Maven-Project?

Comment: I also got the same problem. I tried with `<dependency> <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId> <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId> <version>2.2.11</version> </dependency>` but no luck. same error exists..

Comment: this post doesn't have an answer. Anybody got lucky??

Answer (score 27):

Updating Plugin to **version 0.13.3** fixes this issue.

Answer (score 10):

I resolved this issue by removing any JREs from my Eclipse preferences (Java > Installed JREs) and only leaving the selected JDK there. Even though the JREs were not selected, they still cause the issue and have to be removed. I was able to leave the JREs on my system.
This post was helpful: http://diggingthroughcode.blogspot.ca/2016/05/trouble-with-maven-jaxb2-plugin-and.html

[Update]
Another coworker just ran into this and for him it seemed the critical factor was which Java was being used to run Eclipse.  It won't use what JAVA_HOME is configured too, but the first Java runtime available.  He removed all jres from his system and only left a jdk and that resolved the issue.  I believe the critical factor is whether eclipse is running with a jre or a jdk.  When I resolved the issue I did remove one jre from my system and this was likely what eclipse had been using.  With this jre missing it switched to a jdk even though I had other jres available.  If you don't want to remove jres from your system you can specify what java runtime eclipse should use ([How to run eclipse with different java version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469170/how-to-run-eclipse-with-different-java-version)).  If nothing is specified eclipse will determine the java runtime to use ([Find out what JVM Eclipse is running on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557169/find-out-what-jvm-eclipse-is-running-on)).

Comment: For jaxb2-maven-plugin 2.3.1 and STS 3.9.0.RELEASE Build Id: 201707061823 Platform: Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.0) work too. But I needed run maven directly from console.I think is a Eclipse or Eclipse pluging problem.

Answer (score 5):

This problem was caused by eclipse running on a JRE instead of a JDK.

Edit your eclipse.ini and point to a suitable JDK - for example

```
-vm C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/javaw.exe
```

Comment: Add to update the project after, needed to do that as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37210103/773623)

Answer (score 4):

Same problem here - solved it when I decrease the version.

From :

```
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.1</version>
```

To:

```
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
```

EDIT:

I tried everything else :

-Deleting all the JRE from Eclipse

-Starting Eclipse with JDK

EDIT2:

Check your `.m2` folder. Find the problematic jar and check its size. In some situations Maven could have not download the dependency properly and the `.jar` can exist but have `0kb` size. IF SO: Delete the `.jar` and let Maven download it again.

Comment: This stops the error, but It does not create the hello.wsdl.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> ... </plugin>
            <plugin> ... </plugin>
                  ....
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem:

`Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.3:generate failed: Prefix '' is already bound to ''`

In my case this was due to using Java 10 on a Java 8 project. Switching to the correct Java version resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I know It could be kind of silly but try checking if the all resources (wsdl and xsd) are available in the url that you are giving in the pom.xml